# How to format "datetime -local" value in php fetched from mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime-format

I have an input field in html where I want to echo the value of datetime stored in mysql.

```
<input type="datetime -local" name="schedule" value="<?php echo $result['schedule']; ?>
```

But despite the value being there in mysql db as `YY/mm/dd h:m:s` the `value` is not showing up. What could be the possible issue? When I try to echo outside the input value it displays the result. My thoughts are that the datetime needs formatting according to the html `datetime -local input field.`

Please suggest me any way if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Have you tried supplying the value as an ISO date string (`Y-m-d H:i:s`)? When I inspect the example at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), despite the display value being localized, the underlying value of the input is shown as ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a format character(Timezone abbreviation e.g: EST, MDT…) so you can't use it directly. Escape it (\T) to get a literal T character:

[datetime.format.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash.

```php
<?php
    $date = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($result['schedule']));
?>
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="schedule" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"/>
```

use `<?=$date?>` instead of `<?php echo $date; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are filling it the wrong way. Read the [documentation about the input-type datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) The correct format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM` - note the `T` as divider between date and time.

Also:

1. you wrote the type wrong. Correct is `datetime-local`
2. you are missing the closing quote at the `value` attribute.

Comment: I made a typo above in question, the format is datetime-local and value attribute is closed. value = "<?php echo $result['schedule'] ?>"

Answer (score 0):

This is how to fix it

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="schedule" value="<?php echo $date = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($result['schedule']));?>">
```

Comment: You should explain WHY this is a fix.